# pyspark dataframes loading data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having netflix worksheet in c drive by using pyspark i am not able read data.here is my code

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark

```
df=spark.read.csv("C:\netflix.csv")
df.show()
```

it was showing error in line df=spark.read.csv help me to run it

df=spark.read.csv("C:\netflix.csv")
df.show()

```
 AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/C:
etflix.csv help me to sort it out. given path right but showing error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fo Windows,
Escape `"\"`

i.e. `df=spark.read.csv("C:\\netflix.csv")`